# When I will share one catkin package which folder should I share?

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should I share src, devel, build or installed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220591/when-i-will-share-one-catkin-package-which-folder-should-i-share?/) by [Hieronix](https://answers.ros.org/users/24981/hieronix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-12**:
I've made @joq's answer accepted answer, as mine is really just an image that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The source for a catkin package is typically stored within the src subdirectory in the catkin workspace.

If you want to share the package with someone else, give them a copy of that.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to support @joq's answer, here is a (shamelessly copied) image from the Clearpath Support Centre page on [ROS Workspace structure](https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/articles/202926439-ROS-Workspace-structure):

[image: ROS workspace structure]

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1